# align divs inside a floated list?

Tags: html, css, layout

How can I align the red box on the right ? I tried using `relative` and `margin` but each browser aligns them differently. Some align them farther up and others farther down.

```html
<ul><li>
<img src="" >
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
</li><li>
<img src="" >
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
</li><li>
<img src="" >
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
</li><li>
<img src="" >
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
</li></ul>
```

```css
li {float: left;}
div.one {position: relative; top: 1em; left: 2.5em; width: 5em;}
div.two {position: relative; top: -5em; left: 10em; width: 5em;}
```

[Example Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/divsinsidelists.jpg/)

Comment: @Tim B James and Einacio Take a look at the Example Image link I posted. (I do not have enough reputation to link to an image directly.)

Comment: I did take a look, but I don't know which of the elements you have are supposed to be the red box? I could make any of the elements a red box

Comment: @Tim B James My bad, I should have colored it a different color. It is the one that has the up and down arrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO, Jane.

Here's one way to do this... using `display:inline-block;`

```
li{
    float: left; 
    background:black; 
    border:1px solid green; 
    width:55px;
}

li img{
    display:block; 
    width:55px; 
    margin:0 auto;
}

div.one, div.two{
    background:red; 
    display:inline-block; 
    height:20px; 
    width:20px; 
    margin-left:3px;
}
```

Note: you will need to adjust the measurements to suit your situation.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/SctmD/1/

Comment: inline-block is not supported by IE7 and less. Should be careful when using it

Comment: Thanks @Tim.  Given that IE7 is not just 5% market share - http://www.sitepoint.com/browser-trends-september-2011/ - I tend to ignore it unless the OP states otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to not bother with IE6/7 anymore, but just thought I would note it for Jane ;)

Comment: @ Tim B James Noted, I will add an exception for IE7.